# How to enable "is_nls" parameter in sysdatabases table in sysmaster database in informix?

Tags: database, informix

While creating the database by using the `create database` statement in informix, I couldn't enable `is_nls` parameter in `sysdatabases` table in `sysmaster` database.

How to enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `is_nls` column on the [sysdatabases](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.adref.doc/ids_adr_0221.htm) view over the `sysmaster` is a flag that tells whether  **GLS** is enabled (**1**) or not (**0**).

You should not try to change it over this view nor the `sysdbspartn` table.

If what you're trying to do is change the code set used for a database that it's not possible.

To specify a code set on the creation you must set environment variable [DB_LOCALE](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.glsug.doc/ids_gug_068.htm) for the one you want.

You can check the locale in which the database was created by querying the sysmaster view [sysdbslocale](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.adref.doc/ids_adr_0222.htm).